# Php Get Array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with and I want to get the oddGroupList element in a var.If I do it like this

```
$result=$arr_result['result'];
$betGroupList=$result['betGroupList'];
$betGroupList=$json['betGroupList'];
$oddGroupList=$json['oddGroupList'];
```

I cant get..please enlighten me!

[image: this structure]

Comment: What is this $json variable. It's not mentioned anywhere. Maybe you need `$result= 
 $arr_result['result']['betGroupList']['oddGroupList'];`?

Comment: Missing some array index references in there... [0] ... and please post actual json string, not some image representation of what it thinks the string should be.

Comment: What is $json??

Comment: $json is the json array

Comment: No it's not. You call it $arr_result on first line

Comment: `$var=$arr_result['result']['betGroupList'][0]['oddGroupList'];`

Comment: You override betGroupList variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Check this option:

// Static option:

    $result=$arr_result['result'];
    $betGroupList=$result['betGroupList'];
    $betId = $betGroupList[0]['betId'];
    $layoutType = $betGroupList[0]['layoutType'];
    $betDescription = $betGroupList[0]['betDescription'];
    $oddGroupList=$betGroupList[0]['oddGroupList'];
    $oddGroupDescription =$betGroupList[0]['oddGroupList'][0]['oddGroupDescription'];
    $oddList =$betGroupList[0]['oddGroupList'][0]['oddList'][0];
    $betCode = $oddList['betCode'];
    $oddValue = $oddList['oddValue'];
    $oddDescription = $oddList['oddDescription'];

// Dynamic Option: 

foreach($result['betGroupList'] as $betGroup){
echo $betGroup['betId'];
echo $betGroup['layoutType'];
echo $betGroup['betDescription'];
foreach($betGroup['oddGroupList'] as $oddGroup){
    echo $oddGroup['oddGroupDescription'];
foreach($oddGroup['oddList'] as $odd){
    echo $odd['betCode'];
    echo $odd['oddValue'];
    echo $odd['oddDescription'];
}

}
}
```

Comment: this works but what about all the oddGroupLists should I iterate them?

Comment: Read how to ask a question carefully. Your question is nowhere near a good question.

Comment: If size of array you should iterate to get all variables but if size is static as i see in picture you can get it without any loop.

Comment: @ElizabethD. I wrote both options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$arr_result['result']['betGroupList'][0]['oddGroupList'];
```